# System of equations with complex numbers-circles

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

The system of equations
\begin{align*}
|z - 2 - 2i| &= \sqrt{23}, \\
|z - 8 - 5i| &= \sqrt{38}
\end{align*}
has two solutions $z_1$ and $z_2$ in complex numbers. Find $(z_1 + z_2)/2$.

So far I have gotten the two original equations to equations of circles,
$(a-2)^2 +(b-2)^2=23$ and $(a-8)^2+(b-5)^2=38$.
From here how do I find the solutions?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need the original circle equations?

Comment: The point of this exercise is that you realize that $(z_1+z_2)/2$ must lie on the  line that connects the centres of the two circles.

Comment: Gotcha. I was writing an answer solving those by letting $z=a+bi$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to do is to make a drawing of the two circles. Label their centres $C_1$ and $C_2$, and the two intersections of the circles $I_1$ and $I_2$. Now connect these four points by straight lines, and label as $P$ the point half-way between $I_1$ and $I_2$, which is on the line connecting $C_1$ and $C_2$.

We recognize that we have four triangles, all with a $90$ degree angle. So we can apply Pythagoras. For convenience we label the line-piece $C_1$ to $P$ as $a$; $C_2$ to $P$ as $b$; $I_1$ (or $I_2$) to $P$ as $c$. Now:

$$(a+b)^2 = 45$$

$$a^2 + c^2 = 23$$

$$b^2 + c^2 = 38$$

We eliminate $c^2$ by subtracting the second equation from the third, yielding:

$$(b-a)(b+a) = 15$$

Dividing the first equation by this result gives

$$ \frac {b+a}{b-a} = 3$$

From which it follows that $b = 2a$. So $a$ is one-third of the distance between $C_1$ and $C_2$. Therefore the position of point $P$ is given by $2+2i$ + $(6+3i)/3$ = $4+3i$.

Comment: Sorry if this should be clear, but I'm not really sure how we know we have four right triangles.

Answer (score 1):

You're given the distances of the solution points to $A = 2+2i$ and $B = 8+5i.$

One of the solutions and these two complex numbers give you a triangle in the complex plane, and you know the lengths of all the sides.

We can use Law of Cosines to find the angle $\theta$ that has $2+2i$ as its vertex:

$$38 = 45 + 23 - 2 \sqrt{45} \sqrt{23} \cos \theta \to \cos \theta \approx. 0.466252.$$

The projection of $AZ_1$ onto $AB$ is then $\sqrt{23} \cdot 0.466252 \approx 2.23606$.

Why calculate this?  Because the other solution is symmetric on the other side of $AB$, and what you're asked to find, in essence, is the average of the two solutions, which lies on $AB$.

The unit vector from $A$ to $B$ is $(6 + 3i)/\sqrt{45} = (2+i)/\sqrt{5}.$

So, the solution is

$$(Z_1 + Z_2)/2 = 2 + 2i + 2.23606 \cdot (6 + 3i)/\sqrt{45} \approx 4 + 3i.$$

(The fact that this worked out so nicely makes me think there was an easier way, but oh well ...)

Comment: nice solution. Though one of the tags is algebra precalculus, so I would think there must be an easier way. I think it definitely has to do with finding the midway point between the centers of two circles.

Answer (score 0):

We can also treat this in a way that has little to do with complex numbers.  The line connecting the centers of the circles at $ \ (2, \ 2) \ $ and $ \ (8, \ 5 ) \ $ has a slope of $ \ \frac{5 - 2}{8 - 2} \ = \ \frac{1}{2} \ $ and has the equation

$$ y \ - \ 2 \ = \ \frac{1}{2} \ (x - 2) \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ y \ = \ \frac{1}{2} \ x \ + \ 1 \ \ . $$

Using a theorem from classical geometry, the two intersection points of the two circles lie on a mutual chord, of which the line connecting the centers of the circles is its perpendicular bisector (a fact also used in some way by **M. Wind** and **John**).  Thus, we expect the chord to have a slope of $ \ -2 \ $ .

A relation for the coordinates of the intersection points of the circles can be found by subtracting one circle equation from the other; thus,

$$ \ x^2 \ - \ 16x \ + \ 64 \ + \ y^2 \ - \ 10y \ + \ 25 \ = \ 38 $$
$$ - \ ( \ x^2 \ - \ 4x \ + \ 4 \ + \ y^2 \ - \ 4y \ + \ 4 \ = \ 23 \ ) $$
$$ -------------------- $$
$$ -12x \ + \ 60 \ - \ 6y \ + \ 21 \ = \ 15 $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ y \ = \ -2x \ + \ 11 \ \ . $$

The chord and its perpendicular bisector meet at

$$ \frac{1}{2} \ x \ + \ 1 \ = \ -2x \ + \ 11 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{5}{2} \ x \  =  \ 10 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ = \ 4 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ y \ = \ 3 \ \ , $$

found by inserting the value for  $ \ x \ $  into either of the linear equations we've determined.  Hence, the midpoint of the chord containing the intersections of the circles lies at $ \ z \ = \ 4 \ + \ 3i \ $ in the complex plane.

Though we aren't asked to find them, we can also locate $ \ z_1 \ \ \text{and} \ \ z_2 \ $ . Inserting $ \  y \ = \ -2x \ + \ 11 \ $ into the first circle equation, we produce

$$ (x - 2)^2 \ + \ (-2x + 11 - 2)^2 \ = \ 23 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 5x^2 \ - \ 40x \ + \ 62 \ = \ 0 \ \ , $$

for which the roots are $ \ x \ = \ 4 \ \pm \ \frac{3}{5} \ \sqrt{10} \ $ . [Using the other circle equation instead yields exactly the same quadratic equation.]

We may then calculate $ \ y \ = \ -2 \ (4 \ \pm \ \frac{3}{5} \ \sqrt{10}) \ + \ 11 \ = \ 3 \ \mp \ \frac{6}{5} \ \sqrt{10} \ $ .  Thus, we find

$$ z_1 \ = \ (4 \ - \ \frac{3}{5} \ \sqrt{10}, \  3 \ + \ \frac{6}{5} \ \sqrt{10}) \ \ , \ \ z_2 \ = \ (4 \ + \ \frac{3}{5} \ \sqrt{10}, \  3 \ - \ \frac{6}{5} \ \sqrt{10}) \ \ . $$

(Some brief work with right triangles then tells us that the length of the chord between $ \ z_1 \ \ \text{and} \ \ z_2 \ $ is $ \ \sqrt{\frac{36 + 144}{25} \ \cdot \ 10} \ = \ \sqrt{72} \ = \ 6 \ \sqrt{2} \ $ .)